# Fetch data properly from DB in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have two tabels "Group" (contains groups) and "Schedule" (contains items of schedule of various groups).

Every schedule record has a group_id. There can be many schedule items for a one group.

I want to extract data about schedule table, and sort them by group and print them.

Something like that:

```
Group 1 (group_id=1)
- schedule 1 (id=1)
- schedule 2 (id=2)
- schedule 3 (id=3)
Group 2 (group_id=2)
- schedule 4 (id=4)
- schedule 5 (id=5)
```

It's like an array of schedule items for every group.

How can I do that using Laravel Eloqent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create relation methods on the models like below

On model Group :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    /*
    * Get the schedules of the group
    */
    public function schedule()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class,"group_id");
    }

}
```

On model Schedule :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedule extends Model
{
    /*
    * Get the group of the schedule
    */
    public function group()
    {
      return $this->belongTo(Group::class,"group_id");
    }

}
```

in this way you can get the schedules the belogs to the group or a group which has the schedules

Finally you can do this for your result on your controller

```
Group::with('schedule')->orderBy('groups.id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Group Model

```
public function schedules()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Schedule');
}
```

so you can do something like this

```
$groups = Group::with('schedules')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with relation

you can follow below code :-

In your **Group Model** add following code

```
public function schedule()
{
  return $this->hasMany("App\Schedule","group_id"); // you model path
}
```

So you have many Schedule so we are using `hasMany`
and then get all in controller with the help of `with` method

```
Group::with('schedule')->get()->groupBy(id);
```

here we getting all data with grouping `id` because we fetching data from group  model.